# Asignación de variables

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.
En mi sitio web tengo varios campos para registrar los códigos id de las llantas de un vehículo en el momento en que se montan estas. eso quiere decir que cuento con 4 campos.
Cuando el usuario ingresa los campos, (que pueden ir de 1 a 4), y da ejecutar, estos ID quedan asignados en 4 variables que definí así:

```
$IDM1=$_POST['IDM1'];
$IDM2=$_POST['IDM2'];
$IDM3=$_POST['IDM3'];
$IDM4=$_POST['IDM4'];
```

Luego deseo saber, cuantas campos registro el usuario, para lo cual realizo lo siguiente:

```
$iM=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i=$i+1) {
   $IDM='IDM'.$i;
   while ($$IDM!="") {
   $iM=$iM+1;
   break;
   }
}
```

Ahora en este punto, deseo insertar los datos que registro el usuario para lo cual hago lo siguiente:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i=$i+1) {
$IDM='IDM'.$i;
   while ($$IDM!="") {
   $sql_queryIDMN="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Llan]
   (id,usuario,FechaIngreso)  Values
   ('$$IDM','$Usu',GETDATE())";
   $stmlInserIDMN=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql_queryIDMN);
   break;
   }
}
```

Cuando hago una prueba, identifico que el contador de llantas registradas por el usuario esta bien y los ciclos FOR y WHILE funcionan Ok, pero encuentro el siguiente problema:
Supongamos que el usuario solo registra una llanta cuyo dato registrado es 1039, la cual queda asignada a la variable $IDM1.
Yo pensaba que al poner $$IDM en el INSERT, me iba a salir el dato 1039, pero me sale es $IDM1, ósea que lo que me sale es:

```
$sql_queryIDMN="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Llan]
(id,,usuario,FechaIngreso)  Values
('$IDM1','prueba',GETDATE())";
```

cuando realmente lo que necesitaba que saliera era:

```
$sql_queryIDMN="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Llan]
(id,,usuario,FechaIngreso)  Values
('1039','prueba',GETDATE())";
```

Agradezco me indiquen como puedo hacer para obtener lo que deseo

Comment: Eso te pasa creo, porque tienes la variable llamada $IDM no $$IDM, en el value estás haciendo $$IDM y te lo está cogiendo como cadena e insertando ese valor si quieres que aparezca $ 1039 debes de hacerlo concatenando '$'. $IDM. Espero haberte guiado un poco saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué no declaras el campo donde recoges los datos con el mismo name y como array, o sea algo así: `name="IDM[]"`. Así recibirás un `$_POST['IDM'];` un array con los diferentes valores y no tendrás que complicarte tanto para la inserción, abriendo bucles, redefiniendo variables, etc.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, es interesante la propuesta y voy a aprender sobre array, ya que soy nuevo en la programación.

Comment: Gracias scorpions78, me fue útil la información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evaluar una *variable variable* dentro de una cadena puedes usar la [*sintáxis compleja*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
$sql_queryIDMN="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Llan]
   (id,usuario,FechaIngreso)  Values
   ('${$IDM}','$Usu',GETDATE())";
```

Sin embargo, te ahorras mucho usando simplemente arreglos.
En el formulario:

```
<form ...>
   <input type="text" name="idm[]">
   <input type="text" name="idm[]">
   <input type="text" name="idm[]">
   <input type="text" name="idm[]">
   ...
</form>
```

Y al procesar el formulario:

```
$idm = null;
$sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Llan] (id, usuario, FechaIngreso)
          VALUES( ?, ?, GETDATE() )";
// En este punto se asume que ya tienes declarado $Usu
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, array( &$idm, &$Usu ) );
foreach( $_REQUEST['idm'] as $idm ){   // Recorres cada idm
    sqlsrv_execute( $stmt );
    ...
}
```

Aprovechando las bondades de las sentencias preparadas.